# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function with Tablesorter only in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, tablesorter

Only in safari I get the error:

TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$("table").tablesorter')

In all other browsers it works.
This is my javascript code, and I have putt in the header the scripts to jquery and the tablesorter javascript.
So how can i solve this problem? And why is it only in Safari and not in any other browser?

```
 <script>

$(function() {

  // call the tablesorter plugin
$("table").tablesorter({
    theme : 'jui',
    headerTemplate : '{content}{icon}',
    // hidden filter input/selects will resize the columns, so try to minimize the 
          etc
```

Comment: It is difficult to help unless we get some more information... Can you please share more of your code, `etc` doesn't help. Are you sure that jQuery and the plugin are loading? Is there a `DOCTYPE` specified? Are you loading any other libraries like prototype? Is jQuery being loaded more than once?

Comment: Thanks Mottie, my free webhoster did load jQuery a second time for their ads etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When jQuery is loaded twice, any scripts that are loaded between the two copies get associated with the first copy of jQuery ([ref](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10066)):

```
<script src="jquery-copy1.js"></script>
<script src="myPluginExtendedFromJQ1.js"></script>

<script src="jquery-copy2.js"></script>
<script src="myPluginExtendedFromJQ2.js"></script>

<script>
// all of the jQuery's below are associated with jquery-copy2
jQuery(function(){
  // no problems
  jQuery('#demo-x').myPluginExtendedFromJQ2();

  // error: myPluginAttachedTOJQ1 is undefined
  jQuery('#demo-y').myPluginExtendedFromJQ1();
});
</script>
```

So once the document ready function is called, the `jQuery` calls inside refer to the second copy of jQuery that was loaded.

If this situation is unavoidable, then you'll need to define a variable associated with the first copy:

```
<script src="jquery-copy1.js"></script>
<script>var $jq1 = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script src="myPluginExtendedFromJQ1.js"></script>

<script src="jquery-copy2.js"></script>
<script src="myPluginExtendedFromJQ2.js"></script>

<!-- other stuff -->
<script>
// lets call plugins attached to the first copy of jQuery
// document ready can be called on either version $(function(){ ... })
jQuery(function(){
  // no problems
  jQuery('#demo-x').myPluginExtendedFromJQ2();

  // target first copy of jQuery
  $jq1('#demo-y').myPluginAttachedToJQ1();
});
</script>
```

Please refer to [this jQuery forum post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-copies-of-jquery-causing-issues) for more details.

In addition, I would report this issue to your web host, as they should be checking to see if jQuery already exists before loading it.

Answer (score 4):

in my case the solution was to:

**1.** scripting order

```
jquery-1.11.1.js

jquery-latest.js

jquery.tablesorter.js
```

**2.** Method .ready(function($){}) -  it is important to provide $

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#tableSort").tablesorter(); 
    });
```

Comment: Thank heavens mate! Bugged me for an hour until I added ($) in the `function($)`. Can you explain why this fixes it, and also why in their official getting started guide, there's no `$`?

Comment: The issue is related to my answer. This answer is incorrect in that the loading `jquery-1.11.1.js` needs to be removed - you're loading jQuery twice.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because you're defining more than one jquery script.
I had only this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**And got the same error again and again.**

Then I realized that the error was that! But I was using a Layout which defined another version of jquery. 
***After changing the definition in my Layout the error was gone.***

Comment: This just so happens to be the only answer that worked for me... after going through so many

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. In my case, sequence was the problem.
The sequence adding jquery and tablesorter js is important.
Load jquery first and then tablesorter.

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
```

earlier It was written as

```
<script src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.