# jQuery Tablesorter reflow looks good in Browser dev tools but not on smartphone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tablesorter

Hey guys I hope you can help me with my issue with tablesorter 2.0.

I want  to create a table that reflows on a specific breakpoint. I am using tablesorter 2.0 for jQuery.

It looks perfect in Firefox dev tools but on any web browser on my smartphone itself, it looks like the second picture.

[How it looks in Firefox Dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otI9F.png)

[How it looks on my Iphone X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaybH.png)

```js
// Tablesorter
    function sortTable() {
        $(function() {
            $("#table_ausgabe2").tablesorter({
                theme: 'bootstrap',
                widgets: ["reflow"],
                widgetOptions: {
                    reflow_className: 'ui-table-reflow',
                }
            });
        });
    }

            // Call function on page load
            $(document).ready(function () {
                sortTable();
            });
```

```css
/* REQUIRED CSS: change your reflow breakpoint here (35em below) */
        @media ( max-width: 35em ) {

            /* uncomment out the line below if you don't want the sortable headers to show */
            /* table.ui-table-reflow thead { display: none; } */

            /* css for reflow & reflow2 widgets */
            .ui-table-reflow td,
            .ui-table-reflow th {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                float: right;
                /* if not using the stickyHeaders widget (not the css3 version)
                 * the "!important" flag, and "height: auto" can be removed */
                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
            }

            /* reflow widget only */
            .ui-table-reflow tbody td[data-title]:before {
                color: #469;
                font-size: .9em;
                content: attr(data-title);
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
                white-space: pre-wrap;
                text-align: bottom;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }
```

```html
PHP Code:

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<small style='font-size: 14px;' class='mt-4 ml-4'> * = In Zeile änderbar</small><br>";
        echo "<h3 class='mt-4 ml-4'>Kurzinformation:</h3>";
        echo "<div class='row mt-4 ml-2 mr-2'>";
        echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";
        echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
        echo "<table class='table table-striped tablesorter ui-table-reflow'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Kurzbeschreibung* <button class='btn btn-lg aendern'><ion-icon id='icon_save' name='save-outline'></ion-icon></button></th>";
        echo "<th>Zuständig</th>";
        echo "<th>Maßnahme</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th>";
        echo "<th>Erstellt</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='editable' contenteditable='true' data-id='$row[todoID]' data-field='kurzbeschreibung'>$row[kurzbeschreibung]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[kuerzel]</td>";
        echo "<td>$massnahme</td>";
        echo "<td>$button</td>";
        echo "<td>$deutscheZeit</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think it depends on the order your include the js files. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570548/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-with-tablesorter-only-in-safari

Comment: Yes it was the order of the js files and I had a secret headers sent which I didn't notice. Now it works perfectly fine on the phone. Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: I liked to do help you :-)